# THREEJS - GLB Import & Mapping Image Texture

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to map an Image onto my GLB import, however the GLB is just showing up as black. Not really sure where I'm going wrong here.

```
    let textureLoader= new THREE.TextureLoader();
    let texture = textureLoader.load("images/pexels-luis-quintero-2471234.jpeg");

    texture.flipY = true;

    gltfLoader.load( file.path,  (gltf) => {

        gltf.scene.traverse( (child, key) => {
   
            if(child.isMesh){
                child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
         
                let material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( { map: texture } );
                let sprite = new THREE.Sprite( material );

                child.material.map = sprite;
            }
        });
```

[image]

** Added the texture to :-

`child.material.map = texture`

However the image does not fit to the dimensions of the GLB

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An instance of `THREE.Sprite` is a 3D object similar to `THREE.Mesh`. You can't assign a sprite to the `map` property of a material. Do this:

```js
child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
child.material.map = texture;
```

Besides, if you add a manually loaded color texture to a glTF asset, make sure to add:

```js
texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
```

Comment: Thank you, that's definitely assigned the image.... 
however how would I go about scaling so that the asset fits the dimensions of the GLB Mesh? 

(Added picture example in original thread)

Comment: Can you try to set `wrapS` and `wrapT` of your texture to `THREE.RepeatWrapping` and then modulate its [repeat](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=tex#api/en/textures/Texture.repeat) property?

Comment: Strange, seems to not make any difference at all...

Comment: Consider to author the entire asset in a tool like Blender and then just import it via `GLTFLoader`. This would make it easier to ensure proper texture coordinates/mapping. Modifying a loaded asset is something that you normally want to avoid if possible.